# Same IP from posts using Nginx + Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I'm using a plugin called WP-Polls and I need look all differents IPs to control the voters. So, in this plugin has a function to get ips:

```
### Function: Get IP Address
if(!function_exists('get_ipaddress')) {
    function get_ipaddress() {
        if (empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        } else {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        }
        if(strpos($ip_address, ',') !== false) {
            $ip_address = explode(',', $ip_address);
            $ip_address = $ip_address[0];
        }
        return esc_attr($ip_address);
    }
}
```

This function find an address from REMOTE_ADDR, but this header contains the same ip of the server. So, I can not restrict votes by IP. I tried too, look all header in the same function via ECHO to check all possibilities:

```
echo "HTTP_CLIENT_IP: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
echo "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
echo "HTTP_X_FORWARDED: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
echo "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"];
echo "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR: " .$_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
echo "REMOTE_ADDR: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
echo "REMOTE_HOST: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"];
echo "HTTP_X_REAL_IP: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"];
echo "REMOTE_HOST: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"];
echo "REQUEST_URI: " .  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

But only in my REMOTE_ADDR I can see something (ip from my server).

I think the solution to this problem is within Nginx settings. When I use APACHE instead Nginx everything works correctly getting right information from REMOTE_ADDR.

Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is running PHP through a proxy, so when you try to access `REMOTE_ADDR`, PHP sees Nginx as the remote client, and thus gives you your own IP address. To access this information you will need to rewrite it through the proxy.

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

See https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/forwarding-visitors-real-ip/ for more info.

In my setup, I am using `fastcgi` via `spawn-fcgi` and include a file called `fastcgi_params` which overrides many of the `$_SERVER` variables that are lost in the proxying. The contents of that file are below if it is helpful.

**`fastcgi_params:`**

> ```
> fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
> fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
> fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;
> fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
>
> fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
> fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;
> fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;
> fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT     $document_root;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
> fastcgi_param  HTTPS             $https if_not_empty;
>
> fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx/$nginx_version;
>
> fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
> fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
> fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME       $server_name;
>
> # override for wp-polls plugin
> fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR $remote_addr;
>
> # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
> fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS   200;
> ```

**`_.php.conf:`** - included in my server block for PHP processing in WordPress.

> ```
> location ~ \.php$ {
>
>     # proxy buffers - no 502 errors!
>     proxy_buffer_size            128k;
>     proxy_buffers                4 256k;
>     proxy_busy_buffers_size      256k;
>     proxy_ignore_client_abort    on;
>
>     # fastcgi buggers - no 502 errors!
>     fastcgi_buffering            on;
>     fastcgi_buffer_size          16k;
>     fastcgi_buffers              16 16k;
>
>     # max timeouts (should match php.ini)
>     fastcgi_connect_timeout      600s;
>     fastcgi_send_timeout         600s;
>     fastcgi_read_timeout         600s;
>
>     # index page
>     fastcgi_index                index.php;
>
>     # proxy request to spawn-fcgi running on port 12321
>     fastcgi_pass                 localhost:12321;
>
>     # default fastcgi_params
>     include                      fastcgi_params;
>
>     # override fastcgi_params
>     fastcgi_param                SERVER_NAME $host;
>     fastcgi_param                SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>
>     break;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I'm making a test with fastcgi.

Comment: I updated the answer with the `location` block where I include `fastcgi_params` and then this file is included into various `server` blocks.

Comment: I also just updated it with some proxy buffer configs that I had to use to prevent random 502 errors using WordPress with Nginx.

Comment: I tried making a test in a php outside the plugin and I can get the IP. But, inside the wp-pool.. I just get the server IP. I known this plugin with Nginx?

Comment: Never used the plugin, but it should behave the same way as the rest of WP.

Comment: All configs that you my server contains, but the same problem when try get ip from a function php inside the php.

Comment: I cannot see some error before get ip to change this value in this class wp-polls.php

https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-polls/blob/master/wp-polls.php

Comment: Try using `error_log(print_r($_SERVER, true));` inside that function to print all the info to the error log. Perhaps you need to override the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header?

Comment: Just updated the `fastcgi_params` to include `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` which is what the plugin prefers over `REMOTE_ADDR`. Try it and make sure to start/stop nginx.